# UIButton does not always fire

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

i'm extending UITableViewController and have a uibutton added programtticly to the table footer , for some reason the uibutton fire only when touch in the top part ... as if someting is masking the rest of it and i can't understand what it is 
i have the following code at viewForFooterInSection function:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

UIView* footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, 44.0)];
footerView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
footerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
footerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


goButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[goButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getReport)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[goButton setTitle:@"GO!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[goButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
goButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 20, 220.0, 50.0);

UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed: @"but_go.png"];
[goButton setBackgroundImage:bg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[goButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

if (self.optimizations == nil || self.optimizations.count < 1){
 goButton.enabled = NO ;
}

[footerView addSubview: goButton];

return footerView;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the button's frame fell out of its parent view. You need to increase your `footerView`'s frame size so the whole part of the button contains in the `footerView`. You can try to set `footerView` background color to blue or red to see the actual frame area.